# how to cross add multiple vectors with unequal n with each element in another

Tags: r

If I have

```
A<-c(1,7)
B<-c(8,9)
C<-c(10,11,13)
```

I wish to have

```
 Sum<-c(1+8+10, 1+8+11, 1+8+13, 1+9+10, 1+9+11, 1+9+13, 7+8+10, 7+8+11, 7+8+13, 
        7+9+10, 7+9+11, 7+9+13)
```

Is there an easy way to do that in R?

#### *********update************

Sorry for not being clear before, I really wish to seek for a generalized solution, say I have

```
A<-c(a1,a2)
B<-c(b1,b2)
C<-c(c1,c2,c3)
```

And what I really wish would be

```
 Sum<-c(a1+b1+c1, a1+b1+c2, a1+b1+c3, a1+b2+c1, a1+b2+c2, a1+b2+c3,a2+b1+c1, a2+b1+c2, a2+b1+c3, a2+b2+c1, a2+b2+c2, a2+b2+c3)
```

and keep it in this order regardless of the values of ABC.

## Update 2

The correct answer should be expand.grid(C, B, A)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `expand.grid` with `rowSums`

```
rowSums(expand.grid(A, B, C))

#[1] 19 25 20 26 20 26 21 27 22 28 23 29
```

Some explanation - `expand.grid` returns a row for every combination of `A`, `B` and `C`

```
expand.grid(A, B, C)

#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#1     1    8   10
#2     7    8   10
#3     1    9   10
#4     7    9   10
#5     1    8   11
#6     7    8   11
#7     1    9   11
#8     7    9   11
#9     1    8   13
#10    7    8   13
#11    1    9   13
#12    7    9   13
```

and then we take `sum` for each row.

---

We can also use double `outer`

```
c(outer(outer(A, B, "+"), C, "+"))
#[1] 19 25 20 26 20 26 21 27 22 28 23 29
```

---

**EDIT**

If the order of the output is important, we can `order` them after using `expand.grid`

```
mat <- expand.grid(A, B, C)
rowSums(mat[order(mat$Var1, mat$Var2, mat$Var3), ])
#19 20 22 20 21 23 25 26 28 26 27 29
```

Or if you have many columns and don't want to call each column by name you could do

```
rowSums(mat[do.call(order,mat), ])
#19 20 22 20 21 23 25 26 28 26 27 29
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but upon closer examination I see that you are wrong, the answer should be 19 20 22 20 21 23 25 26 28 26 27 29, not 19 25 20 26 20 26 21 27 22 28 23 29. Could you modify it a little bit?

Comment: Thank you for the update, but it is still not general enough because it assumes that every vector is monotonically increasing, what if C<- c(13, 10,11) and I still wish to keep the order of it? Please see the updates in the question

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `CJ`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(A, B, C)[, Reduce(`+`, .SD)]
#[1] 19 20 22 20 21 23 25 26 28 26 27 29
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry for not being clear in the question, please see the update.

Comment: @BenZ  I looked at the order.  The `CJ` output seems to be in the same order..  You can check the order here `CJ(seq_along(A), seq_along(B), seq_along(C))`

Comment: @BenZ Also, your comment about `C <- c(13, 10, 11)` from the output of `CJ(A, B, C)` is in the same order

Comment: If  `C <- c(13, 10, 11)` ,   `CJ(A, B, C)` is still giving   `19 20 22 20 21 23 25 26 28 26 27 29`, but shouldn't it be  `22 20 19 23 21 20 28 26 25 29 27 26` if the order of `C` is preserved?

Comment: @BenZ  If you check the order `CJ(seq_along(A), seq_along(B), seq_along(C))` this is the order of occurerence.  Not clear about your logic

Comment: Thanks, but I just figured out based on the other answer that it should be `expand.grid(C, B, A)`.  This gives a different answer from `CJ(A, B, C)[, Reduce(`+`, .SD)]` if you try to run it. But I still appreciate your input.